# Unable to change values in DataFrame properly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wish to convert continuous data in a DataFrame to discreet data. I have obtained some split values and I am trying to convert using :

```
for i in range(len(attr)):
  attribute = attr[i]
  split = splitting_values[i]
  x[attribute][x[attribute] <= split] = 0
  x[attribute][x[attribute] > split] = 1
```

splitting_values is a numpy array and x is my dataframe.
the problem when im checking, the dataframe, some colums are completely either 0 or 1 which should not be the case.
What is the correct way to change data of dataframe using conditions

Comment: Well you're explicitly setting them to `0` and `1` respectively, so why is that unexpected? Also please provide some sample data, input and expected output, for clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Is the correct way to change the values?

Comment: You may want to try `np.histogram(x[attribute], bins=splitting_values)`.

Comment: Try using: `x.describe()` to see the dataframe columns at once..

Answer (score 0):

to do this in pandas, we use `pd.cut()`

```
numbers = pd.Series([1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

Giving it a number of cuts will convert it into quantiles of that number (so if you put 4, you'll make it so that the list is cut into 4 equal parts where each cut is at a quartile)

```
pd.cut(numbers, 3)

0    (0.991, 4.0]
1    (0.991, 4.0]
2      (4.0, 7.0]
3      (4.0, 7.0]
4     (7.0, 10.0]
5     (7.0, 10.0]
6     (7.0, 10.0]
dtype: category
Categories (3, interval[float64]): [(0.991, 4.0] < (4.0, 7.0] < (7.0, 10.0]]
```

You can also manually give it bins

```
pd.cut(numbers, bins=[-np.Inf, 2, 4, 6, np.Inf])



0    (-inf, 2.0]
1     (2.0, 4.0]
2     (4.0, 6.0]
3     (6.0, inf]
4     (6.0, inf]
5     (6.0, inf]
6     (6.0, inf]
dtype: category
Categories (4, interval[float64]): [(-inf, 2.0] < (2.0, 4.0] < (4.0, 6.0] < (6.0, inf]]
```